# how to store last 5 checked the form in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, database, mysqli

I developed a gym system which has a Check Page, this page check if the member has finished his subscription or not, when member enter the gym he must enter his number (each member has unique number stored in a database),the Database has more than 1000 members, I want from this page or if there is another way to **Know the last 5 members entered the gym**).

i.e.:

Member1 the first one entered the gym

Member2

Member3

Member4

Member5

Member6

Member7 the last one entered the gym

**I need to store *Constantly* last 5 members entered the gym in a table which has 5 rows.**

**From the above example The last 5 members check the form are :**

**Member3**

**Member4**

**Member5**

**Member6**

**Member7**

If member 8 entered, the table will be from member 4 to 8 and so on.. .

***Note : Every 5 or 10 minutes someone enters.***

Below is simple code just to let you know how this Check Page work

```
<form method="GET" action="">
 <input type="text" name="id" id="checkIn" />
 <input type="submit" value="Check" />
</form>

  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $con = mysqli_connect($host, $dbusername, $password, $dbname);
  $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = $id");

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
   $time = $row['endTime'];
   $today = date("d-m-Y"); 
         if ( strtotime($time) >= strtotime($today) )

                  { echo “he can enter the gym”; }

             elseif ( strtotime($time) < strtotime($today) )

                  { echo “he can’t enter the gym”; }
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). This short example could utterly destroy your server.

Comment: I just wrote that code to let you know how my page work, that was simple, Thank you

Comment: That is the worst possible excuse. It's like leaving a loaded gun on the table while you go and do something else. Accidents happen, and the consequences can be severe. Do not write code like this in the first place. The risks are way too high. As @maaarghk kindly demonstrates, doing it properly is not hard and takes only two more lines of code.

Comment: @tadman a slight exaggeration I think :)

Comment: @vascowhite Hardly. Every day there's headlines about how sites are compromised, credit cards stolen, careers and businesses destroyed, all because of recklessly sloppy code like this. Would you be okay with an electrician wiring up your house temporarily if it could start a fire? How about a surgeon not washing their hands because it's just a little operation, no big deal? Do it right. Don't contribute to this rampant problem. Do you want to risk being the person responsible for an obvious injection hole that someone could hijack your company with?

Comment: @tadman this page has more than 50 lines, and i don't want to make my question incomprehensible, as Vascowhite said, a slight exaggeration, why did you vote down to my question, they blocked my account ? I think my question clear and useful

Comment: I didn't vote down on your question and I have no ability to block your account. Please, **always** demonstrate you're escaping your data properly. To leave that out is to suggest you don't care in the slightest about your application.

Comment: @MohammedF.Ghazo Whilst tadman seems to have a fondness for hyperbolae he is basically right. However, it was me and somebody else that down voted your question.

Comment: @tadman Don't get me wrong, I basically agree with you. However, your exaggerations, however well argued are still exaggerations and don't help to forward the case. More rational argument is a better tool.

Comment: @vascowhite Read the features of [this exploit tool](http://sqlmap.org/), something that can take advantage of even a single lapse of discipline, and tell me I'm exaggerating. One mistake is all it takes to completely compromise your application, your customers, and possibly your career. Don't hand-wave this away as "exaggerating". I'd rather be too strict and never have problems than too lenient and end up in a world of hurt.

Comment: I wasn't waving my hands. I haven't said you're wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few parts to this question - firstly regarding database design. If you want to perform this kind of operation, the simplest way to achieve it is a field `lastCheckedTime` on the database which is the unix timestamp corresponding to the time that a member checked into the gym.

In this case the following SQL can be used to show the last 5 members who entered the gym.

```sql
SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY `lastCheckedTime` DESC LIMIT 5;
```

The two functional parts of this query are:

```sql
ORDER BY `lastCheckedTime` DESC
```

and

```sql
LIMIT 5
```

The first clause tells the SQL server to give you the results in descending order of the time that the member last checked the form. The second tells the SQL server to only return the first five results. If you want to change the order swap `DESC` for `ASC` (ascending).

The value of the `endTime` and `lastCheckedTime` fields should be the direct output of PHP's `date()`  function. `date()` outputs a unix timestamp, which is an integer corresponding to the number of seconds since 1st January 1970 00:00. By storing dates this way you can use simple maths logic to compare dates. The above code essentially converts the timestamp integer into a string and then back to a timestamp again, which is a waste of resources and also less useful in your database.

However - the aim of a well designed database table is that you can pull out any statistics you like about the data in that database using simple logic. Storing times as a timestamp will go a long way towards achieving that. A better (supplementary) method, which would provide a lot more data for the client, would be to create a second table called checkIn, which would have the following columns:

```sql
`id` int(8) PRIMARY KEY,
`memberId` int(8),
`checkedInTime` int(8)
```

Every time a member entered the gym you would simply enter a new row into this table. Then the following query would achieve the same as above:

```sql
SELECT * FROM member JOIN checkIn ON member.id = checkIn.memberId ORDER BY checkIn.checkedInTime DESC LIMIT 5;
```

This would provide the exact same results - however, if your client asks you could also use the checkIn table to generate graphs and data about when the gym is used most frequently, which customers use the gym most often, and other useful information. This is a concept known as database normalisation which I suggest you try to read about and understand - it may seem quite advanced for your current level, but it's worth knowing about from an early stage as it will greatly increase your worth as a developer to be able to design systems which can provide such value to your clients.

---

Not strictly related to the question, there are some basic errors in your PHP code.

Firstly and most importantly it is never allowed to place strings directly from user input straight into a query as this creates [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) bugs. The correct method is to use [parameterised statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with the mysqli class. Thus you would do something such as the following:

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $dbusername, $password, $dbname);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute();
```

The other is the following snippet of code:

```
$time = $row['endTime'];
$today = date("d-m-Y"); 
if ( strtotime($time) >= strtotime($today) )
```

This essentially converts the timestamp (described above) into a string and then back into an integer again. This is not only wasteful but it hinders the goal of good database design as described above.

Comment: I need to know the last 5 typed their numbers in the form not last 5 in Members Table ?
because this table has more than 1000 fields.

Comment: I know - is there a field in the database which indicates when the member last checked the form? I assumed that to be startTime - but if not you would need to create a new field on the table and update the member row to indicate when the member last checked the form. You would then order by that field.

Comment: Actually there is no filed, but i'm gonna create a new field, but the question is how will DESC LIMIT 5 work ? is it calculate the hours, minutes and second descendingly to know the last 5 members ?

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect your questions. Please see the bottom paragraphs to explain why it does not need to calculate hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: Just to buzz you again I added a lot more detail regarding database design.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, I would suggest you to make your query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `members` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

It will get your last 5 members, you can modify it by applying your `where` clause.

Comment: Is that query get last members or last members check the form ?

Comment: If you are saving check in time for each member in the database, you can use `ORDER BY` clause on `checkintime` instead on `id`.